# Argument in the roots of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

I am reading Spivak (Chapter 25 - Complex Numbers) and I need some assistance in understanding the following:
In developing "Theorem 2", which explains the method for finding the n-th roots of a complex number, he explains:

> A complex number $\ z=r(\cos\theta+i \sin\theta)$ satisfies $\ z^n=w$ if and only if
>
> $\cos (n\theta) + i \sin (n\theta) = \cos \phi + i \sin \phi$
>
> From the first equation it follows that $\sqrt[n]{s}$ (which denotes the positive real n-th root of s
>
> From the second equation, it follows that for some integer $k$ we have
>
> $\theta=\theta_k=\frac{\phi}{n}+\frac{2k\phi}{n}$

Could anyone paraphrase (explain a bit) the $\theta=\theta_k=\frac{\phi}{n}+\frac{2k\phi}{n}$ part, please?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Where is the first equation?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\theta_k = \frac{\phi}{n} + \frac{2k\pi}{n}$

Comment: There are a lot of books by Spivak, you should be more specific.

Comment: Thank you very much to all those who answered! We have had internet issues these days in Argentina.
I apologise if my question was not clear enough but I have some problems with MathJAX (I don't know how to use it very well). I will also bear in mind writing detailed bibliography in my future posts to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember that complex numbers (other than $0$) have $n$ $n^{th}$ roots and not just one as you may expect from real numbers.  Of course, even there, for even $n$ there are two roots.  For the even case, picking the positive one as the principal root generally behaves well.

With the complex numbers, it is not possible to pick a principal root that behaves so well.  It is usually necessary to remember all of the possibilities.  The argument $\frac{\phi}{n}$ gives one root.  Adding $\frac{2 k \pi}{n}$ for $k$ from $1$ to $n-1$ gives you the other roots.  Note that this assumes the correction suggested by EuklidAlexandria.